# Bendy Bones Move Up when Scaling?

Tags: armature, bones

So I have a bendy bone that I duplicated using shift + D, but when I try to scale it down to match the size of my characters legs, when I click pose mode it shows that the bones have been shifted upwards?

[image]

How do I shrink my bendy bones on the z-axis without this issue occuring?

Because on edit mode it looks normal, but when I switch to pose mode that is when the issue shows

Comment: The bones are scaling relative to their origins, and based on your screenshot, it looks like the origin isn't centered- it's near the top of the bones

Comment: how do i center the origin?

Comment: Go to object mode and press Crtl+A, then choose "All Transforms"